# How to add options to a dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery Add Values to Select Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499950/jquery-add-values-to-select-options)

How can I empty a dropdown, then add options to it through javascript/jquery?

Comment: see http://www.myphpetc.com/2009/03/jquery-select-elements-tips-and-tricks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
$("select").empty().append("<option value='a'>a</option>");
```

Answer (score 3):

plain javascript:

```
var opt = new Option('someText','someValue' /*,[boolean selected: true/false]*/);
document.getElementById('mySelect').appendChild(opt);
//or
var selct = document.getElementById('mySelect');
selct.options[selct.options.length] = opt;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').empty();

$('select').append($('<option/>').html('text'));
```

Comment: `$.append` returns the nodes from `$("select")` does it not? To do what you are describing I believe you would want `$('<option/>').html('test').appendTo( $('select'));`

Comment: @Kevin, Andy is passing an object `$('<option/>')` into the `.append();` call on the `$('select')` object. How is that functionally different than your method of passing the `$('select')` into the `.appendTo();` call on the `'$('<option/>')` object?

Comment: @jball, I read it wrong the first time through. Thanks for pointing that out. I thought I saw the `.html()` call coming **after** the closing of `.append` (i.e. `.append().html()`). @andy, if you edit your question I can fix my vote :)

Comment: @Kevin: what do you want me to edit?

Comment: doesn't matter. I just want to be able to change my vote and cannot until you edit :P